# How to configure the new adt bundle with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, bundle, adt, configure

I just downloaded the new adb bundle with eclipse, where everything comes pre-configured.
It says that you just unpack the zip, run eclipse and you are done. But then I try to run eclipse, I get the error:

[image]

So. I had Eclipse Juno with all the sdk tools downloaded. But I want to change to the new because usually I read about an error that in the new eclipse version that is fixed.

How can I use the new adb bundle? It did not tell me anything about configuring the environment variables. The old one is configured.
Please help.!!!

Comment: What JDK or JRE version do you have? It is complaining about your JDK release level not being 1.7

Comment: but I have jdk 1.7. Oh, I changed the eclipse.ini where it says 1.6, I changed it for 1.7 to see if that recogizes the 1.7 jdk. I it did not.

Answer (score 0):

Download the new eclipse from the page http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
Choose the eclipse classic 4.2.1 according to your windows or linux.
After that you must download the ADT from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html click on Existing IDE and download it there, after that read this http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you already has downloaded Android SDK then you just need to Download new Eclipse. Run that eclipse & set the Path of SDK like

Window --> Prefrences -->Android then Browse your SDK location

Comment: I have eclipse installed with everything. But the adt bundle from the android page comes with everything also. So, downloading the new eclipse will not help, because the adt bundle comes with the eclipse configured to work in android.